# Accessing properties of drawable shapes through code

Tags: java, android

Assuming I have an `ImageView` defined as:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/my_image_view_background"
/>
```

With `my_image_view_background` being:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">

    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:startColor="#555555"
        android:endColor="#111111"
        android:type="radial"
        android:centerX="0.1"
        android:centerY="0.1"
        android:gradientRadius="70"
        />

    <stroke 
        android:width="5dp"
        android:color="#ff3300"
        />

</shape>
```

Is it possible to access the `my_image_view_background` drawable and change the colour of its stroke in code? Also, is it possible to do that based on the 'state' (pressed/selected/default)?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to re-create ImageButton. You can do all that with that widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes its possible

using GradientDrawable you can do it thru code.

[link:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html)

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[] {0xFFadced4, 0xFF71c2eb });
        gd.setCornerRadius(0f);
        gd.setStroke(1, 0xFF7c279b); //here you can define stroke width
        gd.setCornerRadius(3f);
```

[refer this site:](http://www.dibbus.com/2011/08/even-more-gradient-buttons-for-android/)